# how to give multiple inputs and take SS of all of them

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, pyautogui

So for below is my program,. my intention is to open the webpage and take screenshot of it. Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

```
import webbrowser
import pyautogui, time

url = input()

# input 'https://stackoverflow.com/'

chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'

webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)
time.sleep(10)
screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
screenshot.save("anothertest.png")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I take a screenshot/image of a website using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197172/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-image-of-a-website-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use [Pyppeteer](https://pyppeteer.github.io/pyppeteer/) for this - but the method is similar