# How to take screen shot of the whole webpage , like while scraping to keep evidence we need screenshot of webpage?

Tags: python, html, web-crawler

How to save the cache page with the real webpage structure intact?

Comment: Did you do any research or try?

Comment: I did some research 1)it saves only the top view of the page

Comment: 2)the other option which i got a code i am trying to understand :but that codes output changes the websites structure after saving the cache  (its a code to save the wesite's cache page )

Comment: Can you update the question with code?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197172/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-image-of-a-website-using-python

Comment: Thanks @GRVPrasad , but I am already going through this page , my concern is dont you think this will create big files , Still i will go through it completely and try out the given code