# Web Page To Image With Python?

Tags: python, html, image-processing

Any idea on how to convert a webpage like we would see shown on a browser into an RGBA image with something in python?

I am not looking for the other solutions I have seen that either use scikit or other to pull a .png from a webpage. Nor am I looking for a beautiful soup like solution where I can access specific data from a webpage.

I am seeking a solution that renders the webpage into a pixel buffer that I can then manipulate with something like numpy / cv2. Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I take a screenshot/image of a website using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197172/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-image-of-a-website-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

One of the simple solutions of taking screenshots would be using the Selenium package.
See this example: https://pythonbasics.org/selenium-screenshot/#Take-screenshot-of-full-page-with-Python-Selenium