# How can I make web video capture in Django project

Tags: javascript, python, django, web, image-capture

I am working on a Django Web project. I'm trying to embed the youtube video on my website and click button to capture the video image with dragging the part of it. I followed some codes which use 'canvas2html' in javascript, but it failed catching the video image for some reason.

This is my goal.

1. see the embed youtube video on our site and stop the video when we want to capture.
2. click 'capture' button below and it activates mouse to drag and take the part of image we want to download.
3. capture that part of image and download in our local directory.

How can I solve this challenging situation?

Comment: Did you look at this please: https://www.section.io/engineering-education/integrating-youtube-videos-into-a-django-application/

Comment: Thank you for answering. But this page doesn't tells how to capture the video image

Comment: Capturing image like what ?

Comment: like 'command+shift+4' on mac..?

Comment: Does the video is stopped when you **pause** it ? If it do then you can do that by: **windows + print button** on Windows machine.

Comment: Yes but.. I want to make an button on my web.. capture function of our own, not using tools from individual OS..

Comment: that's the reason I tried to use canvas2html but it didn't work well on capturing embeded video.

Comment: Will you please take a look at [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12031316/18982103)