# is it possible to save a link of a symbol chart as a screenshot from tradingview?

Tags: python, screenshot, tradingview-api

For example i want to open this link using **python request** then :

**extracting the chart of that symbol as .jpg or .png :**

this is the link :
https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=FX:EURUSD&interval=60

i want a way to get that **link chart** as a **screenshot** without opening the browser ?

i want it cause i need it in my trading bots signals .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I take a screenshot/image of a website using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197172/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-image-of-a-website-using-python)

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych i will check it if it does the work :