# Save DIV content as image

Tags: php, javascript, gd

I have a div that shows some content (several images, text, floating elements, etc) and I would like to add the posibility for a user to do something like "Save this content as image".

How can i do that?  I read all the php docs but there's nothing good to do this, even `imagegrabwindow` sucks because of its high load, browser limitations, and also no X/Y or width/height control.

So basically, I want to do this:
Get #div content, click on Save as Image, then the user gets a .JPG or .PNG of that div, as if it were a printscreen (screenshot).

I don't want to pre-generate the content using GD, and neither do I want to save as .PDF.

Comment: oh sorry, didn't read the "no humans allowed" sign

Comment: Maybe a technique like this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713938/how-can-i-generate-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-using-a-server-side-script) will be of assistance?

Comment: Well, that's the problem. What makes you think *we're* human? ;-D

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can really think of is to serialize the contents/placement/attributes of the content in the div, send that to the server, and have the server recreate the same elements, same positioning, same attributes with GD.

Off the top of my head, I'd see maybe inspecting the div and creating basically a form post, something like:

```
POST['images'][0]['file']='plane.jpg'  
POST['images'][0]['position']['x']=23  
POST['images'][0]['position']['y']=13  
...repeat for each image  
POST['text'][0]['content']='this is a plane!'  
POST['text'][0]['size']='10px'  
POST['text'][0]['font']='Arial'
```

The server could use this data to recreate what the user created in their browser.