# jQuery or CSS to display thumbnail of external page

Tags: jquery, html, css, object, thumbnails

I'm trying to display thumbnails of external webpages, similar to how Chrome shows recent favorites when a new tab is opened.  I use an object element like this:

```
<object class="page-thumbnail" type="text/html" src="http://www.foo.com/endpoint.html">
   <p>page 1</p>
</object>
```

Is there a good jQuery/jQuery plugin or CSS example of how to accomplish this?  I've looked at -webkit-transform, for example, but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: I should mention that I don't have security issues for this use case, and there is no requirement to be cross-browser compatible.  I've seen a solution using iframes (webkit-transform), but this doesn't seem to translate to object elements.

Comment: Why in the world are you using an object element??? Otherwise, Duopixel's answer should work just fine.

Comment: ... to be strictly XHTML compliant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to create something that looks like a thumbnail, the catch is that you can't control them via javascript. Also, it will only run on Firefox and Webkit.

http://jsfiddle.net/duopixel/vfTAN/

It's just a css scale transform applied on an iFrame.

Comment: That's the trick I'd seen for webkit tranform + iframe.  Pasting my <object>... element in there it doesn't work.  Any idea how to tweak it?

Comment: Don't use object, it's MS propietary. In your code just replace <iframe> for <object> and it should work.

Comment: It looks like iframe is what I need.  However, <object> was introduced in HTML4 and is not MS proprietary, http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#edef-OBJECT

Comment: IE9 also supports css 2D transformations now. So for your example, adding the rule "-ms-transform: scale(0.5, 0.5) translate(-50%, -50%); " will show a shrunken iframe.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/hh393506#_CSS3_2D_Transforms

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so, no.

There is no JavaScript access to HTML "thumbnails" in the first place, and secondly trying to get a thumbnail from an external URL would be a security problem.

You would have to [create the thumbnails on server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713938/how-can-i-generate-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-using-a-server-side-script) to do this. There is no other way.