# Print a webpage to pdf document using php

Tags: php, pdf

I can see there are a few options for doing this. My question is does any one know of a way that I can simply pass a php web page into a pdf creator and it outputs exactly the same as if it was viewed via a browser? Taking into consideration CSS, images and php functions etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Think [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) is the answer you are looking for as it uses [WebKit](http://www.webkit.org/) to render the webpage just like it would look in a browser and then converts it to a PDF. This saves you writing a load of PHP code to organise the layout of your PDF.

Details from their site:

> Simple shell utility to convert html
>   to pdf using the webkit rendering
>   engine, and qt.
>
> Searching the web, I have found
>   several command line tools that allow
>   you to convert a HTML-document to a
>   PDF-document, however they all seem to
>   use their own, and rather incomplete
>   rendering engine, resulting in poor
>   quality. Recently QT 4.4 was released
>   with a WebKit widget (WebKit is the
>   engine of Apples Safari, which is a
>   fork of the KDE KHtml), and making a
>   good tool became very easy.
>
> - Convert web pages into PDF documents using webkit
> - Adding headers and footers (static version only)
> - TOC generation (static version only)
> - Batch mode conversions
> - (Linux) No longer requires an XServer to be running (however the X11
>     client libs must be installed)

For code and more information on [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) integration with PHP see https://github.com/aur1mas/Wkhtmltopdf

Comment: Other than the rendering quality not being great this looks like the option. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a two-part question really.

- Making a screen shot of a web site into an image [has many good answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713938/how-can-i-generate-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-using-a-server-side-script)
- To generate a PDF, use e.g. the [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) library.

Comment: Or a third option is to use a rendering engine and output the result as a PDF like wkhtmlpdf which uses WebKit to render the page. This saves you writing a load of PHP code to organise the layout of your PDF. http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it's a PHP web page makes no difference.  In order to create a PDF that looks like the web page should look, you need to *render* the page - this is what a web browser does when you visit it.

You'll need to use a web browser engine such as Gecko to produce the page layout, then export that as an image and stick it in a PDF.  This can be done programatically.

Answer (score 0):

There are php modules/classes for PDF generation, and there are ways of using CSS to better prepare a page for printing (to pdf).

PHP cannot 'see' the page as the browser sees it.

Comment: I think this is the point exactly I have an application site that includes pages of code using function to print aspects, images, advanced CSS etc. I do not want to spend months going through it all to make it PDF compatible or have to duplicate pages of code specifically for the purpose of PDF.

Answer (score 0):

In more recent years chrome headless has drastically improved for rendering html to
direct PDF output, there can be limitations so not always suited to everyone.

One UpToDate project to **"Make PDF" on a PHP base is https://github.com/chrome-php/chrome**

Requirements
Requires PHP 7.3-8.2 and a chrome/chromium 65+ executable.

example usages

```
   // get page title
    $pageTitle = $page->evaluate('document.title')->getReturnValue();

    // screenshot - Say "Cheese"! 
    $page->screenshot()->saveToFile('/foo/bar.png');

    // pdf
    $page->pdf(['printBackground' => false])->saveToFile('/foo/bar.pdf');
```

It has many API type abilities and is actively maintained at present with few open issues, however it will be restricted by chromes accessible options.