# how do I process dynamically generated graph with PHP and send the result as an email?

Tags: php, javascript, highcharts, phpmailer

I am trying to send mail using phpmailer, so my function which is returning body of mail,is like  :

```
function get_include_contents(){
// some code
 include "graph.php"
  //some code<br/>
}
```

"graph.php" file is actally generating a table and graph (i am using highchart.js) ,

when I run my file to send mail , I am getting table only (which is generated in php).
I am not getting graph(which is geneated in by javascript).

How should I display graph in mail ?

Answer (score 0):

Imho you're best shot is to make a pdf out of the graph.php page and use that pdf as an attachment in your email. This process has been discussed here [Print a webpage to pdf document using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142080/print-a-webpage-to-pdf-document-using-php)

Comment: Thanks your input , but for client ,they have to download the pdf to see the results !!!!

Comment: Depends on his email client. Some show a preview of attachments in the message.

Comment: You could also just add a link to the php page in the email.

Comment: Putting javascript in the email is just not an option for so many reasons. Putting the generated html in there is probably not an option either as most email clients only accept a really restricted set of html and you'll have major trouble getting the email client to show want you want. Getting it cross email client is even more difficult since each one renders html differently. Web clients tend to be even worse.

Comment: The main problem is that you want dynamic data in a medium (email) that was designed for static data. That's just asking for trouble.

Comment: Thanks man , Finally I switched to libchart php library .It's working fine .