# How to embed fonts into a PDF with TCPDF?

Tags: php, html, pdf, tcpdf

I have tried to use TCPDF whose code is given below:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tcpdf/tcpdf.php'); 
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 061');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
if (@file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10); 
$html ="";
$pdf->AddPage();
$html .='<style>'. file_get_contents('http://localhost/Projects/PDF/css/style_4.css').'</style>';
$html .= file_get_contents("http://localhost/Projects/PDF/mycon.php"); 
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->lastPage();
$pdf->Output('example_061.pdf', 'I');
```

The above code generates a PDF successfully but is not taking my CSS and fonts that I have defined into "style_4.css" and included externally.

I have also tried to include CSS on the page itself "mycon.php" but its not taking from there as well. What am I doing wrong?

**Note:** I have different fonts which will be dynamically attached with layout based on certain conditions.

Comment: You could try PrinceXML, but a server license is very expensive indeed (though I think a free version is available for certain kinds of use). I understand it is considered to be the most robust web-to-PDF solution available, in terms of its implementation of paged media. However, you could try `wkhtmltopdf` as well - that uses WebKit internally and so may be okay for your needs. Bear in mind though that broad requests for libraries tend to be off-topic here, since such questions show their age quickly.

Comment: @halfer thanks for your reply ,Now I have updated my question, please check it now! And I have also tried with your suggestion but did not get any good help so that i can implement that.

Comment: That's now on-topic IMO, so I'll cast a re-open vote. If you want to carry on researching the topic, you want to **embed fonts** - so if you search for "TCPDF embed fonts" you may find the answer. (It may however turn out [to be a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=embed+fonts+tcpdf)).

Comment: @halfer what if I have used multiple fonts in my page?

Comment: @TheMohanAhuja: Just `$pdf->addTTFfont()` each of them - you'll get a different font handle from each of the calls.

Comment: i have checked for how to embed fonts it is working fine for single fonts but i have multiple fonts used in my web page so do i need to add them separately and also i have a doubt that can't be used all that fonts from css itself because this is for one page, so I will add required fonts but what if i will use same code for generate pdf for another url ?

Comment: @DeepakGoswami: From your comments on an answer, you seem to have fallen into an XY problem - you seem to _actually_ want a PDF screenshot of a webpage. Next time, please include your end goal in the problem description. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/19746

Comment: I am not getting what do you mean by "PDF screenshot of a webpage." ?

Comment: @DeepakGoswami: In goes an URL address, out comes a PDF file. The PDF file contains the webpage as it would display in a web browser.

Answer (score 2):

See TCPDF's [documentation](http://www.tcpdf.org/fonts.php):

> Using the addTTFfont() method you can directly create a TCPDF font
>   starting from a TrueType, OpenType or Type1 font. NOTE: The 'fonts'
>   folder must be writeable by the webserver.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> $fontname = $pdf->addTTFfont('/path-to-font/DejaVuSans.ttf', 
>                                 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
> ```

Comment: I have a small doubt in my mind why we are adding fonts using this additional code although i have added all that fonts into my css file. i am asking this only because the url of web page can we changed and for that fonts are also changed so in that case the above code will not work ?

Comment: @DeepakGoswami: Because the TCPDF code does not do it automatically. I would be happy if it did, but that doesn't make it happen ;)

Comment: (note that TCPDF seems to be open source, so if you're feeling up to the - nontrivial - challenge of implementing this, you can)

Comment: :ok thanks, so what do you think is there any other open source API or Lib that generate pdf for a web page url? because it seems to very hard for me to include all that fonts using the above code.

Comment: @DeepakGoswami: You mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=webpage+pdf+%5Bphp%5D

Comment: @DeepakGoswami: I don't think there's a free API for that. I have successfully used wkhtml2pdf for a similar effect. See the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5142302/19746

Comment: Link is no longer valid.

Comment: Software seems to be obsolete and not under further development anyway :(