# PDF Content get changed From Application view to downloaded files

Tags: php, pdf, download, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF to generate the PDF, when I open a PDF file on my browser within the application use, with URL viewDocument.php look like these,

[image]

And when it is **downloaded**, view downloadDocument.php

[image]

Not understanding why this problem is occurring, really do not understand.Please Help!!

Comment: you are missing the fonts in your system. download and install the same font in your pc/laptop

Comment: Or add the fonts into the PDF, if you want it to work on every system - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663625/how-to-embed-fonts-into-a-pdf-with-tcpdf (That this will increase the file size of the PDF, should be obvious.)