# HTML to Image conversion

Tags: java, html, image

I am working on a project using Spring 3.0 and Hibernate 3.x which requires the conversion of HTML pages (either from URL or File) to images. This can be done through command line tools or java libraries. Opensource is ok. HTML 5 and CSS 3.0 support is important.

Comment: So you want a screengrab of the rendered html page?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963900/php-library-for-converting-html-to-image

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Convert web page to image"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968201/convert-web-page-to-image)

Comment: @Pheonix If you're going to point the OP to another question, probably best if it isn't the duplicate of a duplicate. The original is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713938/how-can-i-generate-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-using-a-server-side-script

Comment: @Grim: that question isn't marked as a duplicate...

Comment: See WKHTMLPDF http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ they mention on their site that there is wkimagetopdf for **html to image** conversions, It is almost the best html to pdf conversion library available, I haven't tried it for html to image conversions , you can check it out It might be helpful

Comment: @MGA : Thanks MGA! It is very good tool and it is what I was looking for. You could post above comment as answer.

Comment: @Nandkumar I reformulated the question. I hope it suits what you were asking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [**WKHTMLPDF.**](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/)

They mention on their site that there is ***wkimagetopdf*** for *html to image conversions*, It is almost the best html to pdf conversion library available, I haven't tried it for html to image conversions , But I think it worth that  you check it out.