# Display image after image upload

Tags: php, file-upload

I am developing a social website.In the user registration page,user has the provision to add his photo.I have done this with little effort.My problem is that I want to display the image which has been uploaded by the user to a div,before clicking the submit button at the end of the form.I have searched a lot,but couldn't get the right one.

My html code is like this:

```
 <img src="<?php echo $row_picture;?>" name="picture" class="settingspic"  width="75" height="91" alt="profile pic" name="picture"/><a href="" onclick="return uploadimg()"> Upload</a></li>
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="display:none;" />
```

My jasvascript code is:

```
function uploadimg()
{
 var uploader = document.getElementById('file');
 uploader.click();
 return false;
}
```

Comment: Use ajax to instantly display your uploaded image

Comment: @ Pavan K I am not inserting the image path name to database until user clicks the submit button

Comment: Yes i knw, just use ajax to upload the image and show the image , there is also a plugin for this

Comment: are you looking for [this](http://www.webmotionuk.co.uk/jquery-image-upload-and-crop-for-php/).. just [google search](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=php+ajax+upload+image&aq=f&oq=php+ajax+upload+image&aqs=chrome.0.57j60l2j0l3.6578&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&tbo=d&biw=1920&bih=979&sclient=psy-ab&q=php+ajax+upload+crop+image&oq=php+ajax+upload+crop+image&gs_l=serp.3...2364.3841.0.4131.5.5.0.0.0.3.733.1761.4-1j1j1.3.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.XgmHloXay-Q&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1357316858,d.Yms&fp=70b0c17457ab5a6) will do.

Comment: @ Pavan K I understood.Is there any plugin for it???

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713938/how-can-i-generate-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-using-a-server-side-script) it may help you

Comment: @ Pavan K can you please provide

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a Ajax call to fetch the uploaded image instantly .

Reference URL => http://www.finalwebsites.com/demos/php_ajax_upload_example.php

Comment: @ jenis This is not I require.I need to display the image when user upload it,before the user submits the form

Comment: @Anaz A doubt you can do that. In fact, with simply PHP and file uploads using html forms, the file isnt actually uploaded until you submit the form...

Comment: @teh1 Ya,I know that.My requirement is to display the image before submitting,just like facebook registration page

Comment: @Anaz No doubt you have to use Ajax script for it

Comment: Facebook uses different ways of uploadin images (using javascript). You can use search engines for that... http://www.9lessons.info/2011/08/ajax-image-upload-without-refreshing.html?m=1

Answer (score 1):

Jquery File Upload plugin is the one that you want.

http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

this will help because in above plugin as you asked "before submitting form you want to show image in div" this plugin working that way.

**try it**

Answer (score 0):

here many plugins r present, I guess most of them wil be useful for your project

http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-ajax-file-uploader-plugins/