# PHP imagegrabscreen on linux?

Tags: php, linux

I'm trying to get a screenshot of my visitors!

Normally its working with `imagegrabscreen` but I got a Linux Server.

```
<?php
$im = imagegrabscreen();
imagepng($im, "myscreenshot.png");
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

I get this error:
`Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagegrabscreen() in /var/www/index.php on line 2`

How can I fixed that on Linux?
Or is there a other possible way to do that?

Comment: From [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagegrabscreen.php), this function is Windows-specific.  In terms of other options, have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713938/how-can-i-generate-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-using-a-server-side-script)?

Comment: @Ironcache yes, but he want a screenshot of websites...

Comment: What do you want?

Answer (score 0):

`imagegrabscreen()` is not working on LINUX.
It can only be used on Windows.