# Need help with google's search feature of pre-displaying the website

Tags: php, ajax, search, iframe

I have been thinking about this new( I know it has been a while ;p) google's feature that displays the website in the search result.

What i don't kind of get is, how they did it? Is it a form of iframe? or is it a php render of the page? Is it dynamic JavaScript/Ajax? I am just very curious how they have done it? And the follow up question would it possible for us to duplicate for our own sites? Like a search result page to display the page on mouse hover.

Any assistance would be most appreciated? I searched everywhere i could not get a definite answer anywhere?

Comment: google don't use PHP and PHP doesn't render anything

Answer (score 3):

The thumbnail is rendered by some kind of browser engine, and stored in an image file. There are lots of providers of this service, for example [Thumbshots](http://www.thumbshots.com/), [WebSnapr](http://www.makeuseof.com/dir/websnapr/) and [ShrinkTheWeb](http://www.shrinktheweb.com/).

Answer (score 2):

It is a thumbnail rendered on server side, and stored in an image file.

There are questions on SO dealing with how to do this, e.g.:

- [How can I generate a screenshot of a webpage using a server-side script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713938/how-can-i-generate-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-using-a-server-side-script)
- [How can I take a screenshot of a website with PHP and GD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627301/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-of-a-website-with-php-and-gd)
- [How might I obtain a Snapshot or Thumbnail of a web page using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443837/how-might-i-obtain-a-snapshot-or-thumbnail-of-a-web-page-using-php)